# Typeerror myFunction.map not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error:

Typeerror myFunction.map not a function

Below is my code

```
 <div className="myPoints">
      {myPoints.map((point, idx) => { etc etc
```

Comment: Did you read the error?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native map to the Object, map method direct use with array only, so you have to get the object's key for reference, i.e:

```
Object.keys(myPoints).map((point, idx) => {
  console.log(myPoints[point]);
});
```

For better reference of Object.key [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and for array.map [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)